# Complex Javascript for performing a basic job

Tags: javascript

I came across a website that was using a very strange piece of code with a lot of variables and recursive functions just to forward the user to the main website. The code was obfuscated. After deobfuscation, it is as follows. Note that the `go()` function is executed upon click of a button named 'Enter Site':

```
(function (paetynn, jaquez) {
  var lyons = quetzali, payzli = paetynn();
  while (!![]) {
    try {
      var kyona = parseInt(lyons(295)) / 1 + -parseInt(lyons(300)) / 2 + parseInt(lyons(299)) / 3 + -parseInt(lyons(301)) / 4 * (parseInt(lyons(304)) / 5) + -parseInt(lyons(294)) / 6 * (parseInt(lyons(298)) / 7) + parseInt(lyons(297)) / 8 * (-parseInt(lyons(303)) / 9) + parseInt(lyons(305)) / 10;
      if (kyona === jaquez) break; else payzli.push(payzli.shift());
    } catch (zulekha) {
      payzli.push(payzli.shift());
    }
  }
}(niree, 850584));
function quetzali(winston, ikeshia) {
  var hongan = niree();
  return quetzali = function (khole, kysin) {
    khole = khole - 294;
    var zebulan = hongan[khole];
    return zebulan;
  }, quetzali(winston, ikeshia);
}
function go() {
  var amey = quetzali, gracelee = amey(296);
  document[amey(302)] = gracelee, window.location = "/";
}
function niree() {
  var saana = ["604264sauqJi", "10214183nDqKAH", "2078325AmAiPo", "1206860TDYYcJ", "4VhIfuJ", "cookie", "45pazGrL", "380390DQkmbn", "12476230senONL", "6bRFHSG", "1426528LpTiXE", "session_keys=mycheck;"];
  niree = function () {
    return saana;
  };
  return niree();
}
```

I don't fully understand what the code does. Could some JS expert clarify on the piece?

Seems like the code is manipulating window.location.
Also it was used inside a script tag inside the head tag of the page.

Comment: Basically it sets a cookie. `amey(296)` returns `cookie` and `amey(302)` returns: `session_keys=mycheck;`

Answer (score 2):

This code sets cookie `session_keys=mycheck;` and then redirects to /. The rest of code make permutation in the array of strings `saana` so analizyng code would be more difficult.

Comment: Why would they write such a complex code to do such a basic job?

Comment: @MehdiHaghgoo as you can make use of [overrides](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/new-in-devtools-65/#overrides) in basically all browsers, you can change the whole page as you want to. From [obfuscator.io](https://obfuscator.io/), which was used in your example - `This tool transforms your original JavaScript source code into a new representation that's harder to understand, copy, re-use and modify without authorization. ` - The more complex the code gets, the harder it will be to find the important routines or the source of an error.

Comment: @MehdiHaghgoo they didn't write such code. As Christopher said, they used tool, that generates it from a normal code. If you use tools like Webpack, adding obfuscaton is verry easy, just importing library and adding to config, so you don't need ny important reasons to do it.